# how to print some letters from a string in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I had a table like bellow image. I want 2,3 letters from the column "name" [image]

The result is like bc,da,bc,bc,bc,bc

Comment: `substring()`:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name,2,2) AS ShortComp FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the string function LEFT() to return the leftmost specified number of characters, like this:

```
SELECT LEFT(name, 2) AS ShortComp FROM table;
```

Comment: Ahh, my apologies...just realized that I misunderstood the original question. This solution only works if you are starting from the left edge of the field and want everything left-to-specified-character-number. Maybe it will help someone else =)